# Core Plot Tick Marks on Both Sides of Axis?

Tags: ios, core-plot

Is it possible to position tick marks in the center of an axis?

I don't have enough reps to post images, but here's the general idea...

--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `tickDirection` property of the axis. The default (`CPTSignNone`) centers the tick marks on the axis as shown in your drawing.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you, Eric. Worked like a charm.

Comment: I would up-vote this answer too, but I'm still working on rep points:)